# AnyObject and Any in Swift

Tags: swift, value-type, reference-type

I don't understand when to use `AnyObject` and when to use `Any` in Swift.

In my case, I've a `Dictionary`

> [String: ???]

??? : Can be `Int`, `Double`, `Float`, `String`, `Array`, `Dictionary`

Can someone explain me the difference between `Any` and `AnyObject`
and which one to use in my case.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

`AnyObject` is only for reference types (classes), `Any` is for both value and reference types.

So you should go for `[String: Any]`.

> **Type Casting for Any and AnyObject**
>
> Swift provides two special types for working with nonspecific types:
>
> - `Any` can represent an instance of any type at all, including function
>     types.
> - `AnyObject` can represent an instance of any class type.
>
> **NOTE:**
>
> Use `Any` and `AnyObject` only when you explicitly need the behavior and
>   capabilities they provide. It is always better to be specific about
>   the types you expect to work with in your code.

From **The Swift Programming Language**:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-ID342

-

Also note that when you work with Cocoa API, it's common to receive an Array of AnyObject, this is because Objective-C arrays are NOT typified.
So you need to cast them to the array type you expect.

-

**EDIT:** (december 22, 2015)
On the last statement, note that this is changing with Swift 2.0 and Xcode 7.
Apple has introduced [‘Lightweight’ generics](http://www.thomashanning.com/objective-c-lightweight-generics/) in Objective-C so lots of Cocoa APIs now already returns the correct type.

**EDIT:** (october 18, 2016)
Note that, as of Swift 3.0, Objective-C `id`s are now imported as `Any`, not anymore as `AnyObject`.

Comment: Note that `String`, `Array` and `Dictionary` are not classes, for these use Any.

Comment: Nor Int, Double and Float are.

Comment: Yeah but that is usually obvious. It is not so obvious that `NSString`, `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` are classes yet the similarly functional Swift versions are not classes and that trips up many devs.

Comment: Does Any represent optionals too ? Or should that be expressed as Any?

Comment: @robdashnash *AnyObject* is for classes, *Any* is for everything else. Optional<type> is an enumeration with two cases: *none* and *some(value)*, which you can unwrap the *value* with "!", so logically I would go with *Any* for it. But I haven't been actively looking at Swift for one year, so you'd better try it yourself.

Comment: @robdashnash Any does not represent optionals. ? should be added to make it optional

Answer (score 53):

Whether you use `Any` or `AnyObject` depends on your intended use:

If your dictionary will be used only within Swift code, then you should use `Any` because your types (`Int`, `Double`, `Float`, `String`, `Array`, and `Dictionary`) are not objects.

If you will be passing your dictionary to Objective-C routines that expect an `NSDictionary`, then you should use `AnyObject`.

When you `import Foundation` or `import UIKit` or `import Cocoa`, it is possible to declare your array as `[String: AnyObject]`, but in this case Swift is treating your `Int`, `Double`, `Float` literals as `NSNumber`, your `String`s as `NSString`, your `Array`s as `NSArray`, and your dictionaries as `NSDictionary`, all of which are objects.  A dictionary using `AnyObject` as the value type is convertible to `NSDictionary`, but one using `Any` is not.

Answer (score 4):

According to Apple’s Swift documentation,

- Any can represent an instance of any type at all, including function
  types and optional types.
- AnyObject can represent an instance of any class type.

For more details please check this: [Blog](https://medium.com/@mimicatcodes/any-vs-anyobject-in-swift-3-b1a8d3a02e00)

Answer (score 2):

[Check this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31041265/difference-between-generics-and-anyobject-in-swift):

> Generics are type safe, meaning if you pass a string as a generic and try to use as a integer the compiler will complain and you will not be able to compile your (which is good). (This happens because Swift is using Static typing, and is able to give you a compiler error).
>   If you use AnyObject the compiler has no idea is this object can be treated as a String or as an Integer and basically will allow you to do whatever you want with it (which is bad) as if you try to use an object that has been passed as a String when it is an Integer the application will crash. (This happens because Swift is using Dynamic typing and will only give you a runtime error)

Answer (score 1):

By the default we should use "Any" and if we need more precision then we can chose more constrained types like AnyHashable, AnyObject, AnyClass, CustomType etc.

AnyObject should be used when sanding an object to frameworks which were written in Objective-C like UIKit and Foundation.

AnyObject accepts an instance of a class types and instances of types like enum, struct and optional class types objects are not accepted:

```
class CustomType {
   var instanceArg1: Int
   var instanceArg2: String
   static var classArg1: Int
}
```

Particularity of the AnyObject type is that an object of this type has access to all @objc methods and variables by autocompletion. If UIKit or Foundation are imported then the AnyObject instance object has access to all variables and methods of all Foundation objects by autocompletion.

the code below, compiles but crashes the app in runtime first of all due to the fact that given argument is of type String and not of UITableView and there is no a method tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection) defined in String type.

```
import UIKit

class CustomType {

    func customMethod(arg1: AnyObject) {
        let tableView = UITableView()
        let numberOfRows = arg1.tableView(tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: 0)
    }
}
```