# Swift: If I copy AnyObject that is JSON data, will the data be copied or passed by reference?

Tags: json, swift

I get JSON data as a result of `NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest` and deserialize it to `AnyObject`:

```
var error: NSError?
let jsonObject: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: &error)
```

I want to pass it to a completion handler for parsing `jsonObject` into structured data.

**Question:** will `jsonObject` be passed by reference or deep-copied? The question arises since `Array` and `Dictionary` that JSON consists of are value-type in Swift.

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25809377/4777613) to related question that says that objects inside Foundation are indeed `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`, i.e. reference types. Is it the same with JSON data?

Comment: Why is it relavent where the object came from?  Why would a reference type be passed by value?  `AnyObject` is a reference type.

Answer (score 1):

Class objects (`AnyObject`) are always passed by reference.

Answer (score 0):

- JSON result data consists of NSArray and NSDictionary which are
  reference-type. If you get result data into **jsonObject** which is
  of type **AnyObject?** and you passed it in completion handler then
  it will depends upon **type** of variable inside completion handler
  that whether it will passed by refrence or deep values will copied.
  If inside completion handler variable for catching **jsonObject** is
  of type **AnyObject** then reference will passed and if completion
  handler variable is of particular **Array** or **Dictionary** type
  then it will deeply copied **jsonObject's** value.
- Also one more thing is that if your completion handler variable is of particular type then you should know the JSON result format already otherwise it will not parsed properly.

Comment: Yes, but nowadays (5/2018) this is irrelevant in practice since all JSON values are value type anyway.