# Conform to a protocol misunderstanding

Tags: swift, swift2

```
class SuperDelegate <T: AnyObject> {

  func addDelegate(delegate: T)
  {

  }
}
```

My question is about `T` key, does it mean the same as `id` in Objective-c? I mean about case of uses.

how to understand the first line `class SuperDelegate <T: AnyObject>` Sorry I am new in Swift.

As Objective C program for me this line means that we make class to conform a protocol that has to implement all required method. But I don't understand `func addDelegate(delegate: T)` is this the same like

`- (void)addDelegate:(id)delegate` which is a property `id <T> delegate`.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and read: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH3-ID0.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct in your assumptions that [AnyObject behaves like id](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID35):

> You can call any Objective-C method and access any property on an
>   AnyObject value without casting to a more specific class type. This
>   includes Objective-C compatible methods and properties marked with the
>   @objc attribute.

but you have [used it here as a generic type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31041298/1694526) rather than as a concrete type that should be cast to. The class is requiring a type that adheres to the AnyObject protocol but it isn't forcing it to be AnyObject (see header files: cmd + click on AnyObject inside Xcode).

So your instance could be instantiated `SuperDelegate<AnyObject>` but it could also be instantiated `SuperDelegate<NSDate>`. This means that the whole subset of ObjC methods and properties cannot be guaranteed as they can with a cast to AnyObject as a concrete type because at runtime `T` might represent `NSDate` or `NSNumber` or any other class.

To achieve what you want you would need to write:

```
class SuperDelegate {
    func addDelegate(delegate: AnyObject)
    {

    }
}
```

But Swift is a strongly-typed language and it would normally be the case that you had a delegate protocol and that the delegate for your type adhered to the delegate protocol:

```
protocol DelegateProtocol {
    func somethingHappened()
}
struct MyTypeDelegate:DelegateProtocol {
    func somethingHappened() {
        print("Thanks for telling me!")
    }
}
struct MyType {
    var delegate:DelegateProtocol?
    func tellDelegateSomethingHappened() {
        delegate?.somethingHappened()
    }
}
let del = MyTypeDelegate()
var type = MyType()
type.delegate = del
type.tellDelegateSomethingHappened()
```