# Usage of Generics

Tags: swift, generics, types

I have the following structs:

```
struct A<T> {
    var val: T
}

struct B<T> {
    var setOfA: Set<A<T>>
}
```

Is this incorrect usage of generics, if the set of `A`s can have values of both `A<Int>` and `A<Float>` type (or any other type)?

If yes, is using `Any` the correct way to do this?

Would generics have been the right way to go, if the set of `A`s was constrained to `A<>`s of a single type?

Comment: You might just be able to make them conform to the [Numeric Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/numeric?changes=_4) instead.

Comment: Int and Float were just examples. It could literally be of any type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Generics and AnyObject in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31041265/difference-between-generics-and-anyobject-in-swift)

Comment: You need to make your  struct and generic type conform to Hashable. `struct A<T: Hashable>: Hashable {
    var val: T
}` and `struct B<T: Hashable> {
    var setOfA: Set<A<T>>
}`

Comment: @LeoDabus There is no need for `struct B` to conform to `Hashable`, and there's neither a need for `T` to do that. With the generic type `T` in `B`, the `A`s in the `Set` can only be of the same type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Swift is a moving target, all code tested using Xcode 9.2 & Swift 4.0.*

First if you wish to insert `A<T>` items into a set then the type must implement the `Hashable` protocol. You can implement this protocol as needed but for illustrative purposes a simple approach is to require the type parameter `T` to be `Hashable` and to implement the protocol by indirecting to `val`:

```
struct A<T> : Hashable where T : Hashable
{
    var val : T

    var hashValue: Int { return val.hashValue }

    static func ==(lhs: A<T>, rhs: A<T>) -> Bool
    {
        return lhs.val == rhs.val
    }
}
```

The rest of the answer does not require the above implementation, just that `A<T>` is `Hashable`.

Constraining your `Set` to only containing instances of `A<T>` for any and all `T` is more of a challenge. One approach to this problem is to use an *existential type*, which in this context essentially allows the wrapping of differently typed value inside another non-generic wrapper. Swift has some pre-defined existential types, in particular `AnyHashable` which you could use to define `B`'s `var`:

```
struct B
{
    var setOfA : Set<AnyHashable> = Set()

    ...
}
```

Unfortunately this does not constrain the set to only hold values of type `A<T>` for any `T`.

The type of `setOfA` cannot be `Set<A<AnyHashable>>` as that would require a value of type `A<T>` for some `T` to be cast-able to `A<AnyHashable>` and Swift does not support that (researching *variance* might help understand why).

You might wonder why the type cannot be `Set<Hashable>`. Unfortunately (in this context!) `Hashable` is a *protocol* with a `Self` requirement and Swift does not support using it as a generic type parameter in this context. `AnyHashable` is a *non-generic* `struct` which *type erases* (the *existential type* bit) the value it wraps.

So back to solving the problem of constraining the set to only contains `A`'s. One solution is to hide (`private`) the set inside `B` and provide a generic insertion function which only accepts `A<T>` values, for any `T`. The set value itself can then be made public using a read-only computed property. For example:

```
struct B
{
    // private property so only B's functions can modify the set
    private var _setOfA : Set<AnyHashable> = Set()

    // public read-only property so _setOfA cannot be changed directly
    var setOfA : Set<AnyHashable> { return _setOfA } 

    // public insert function which only accepts A<T> values, for any T
    mutating func insert<T>(_ element : A<T>) -> (Bool, A<T>)
    {
        return _setOfA.insert(element)
    }
}
```

Here is dome sample code using the above:

```
let x = A(val: 4)        // x : A<Int>
let y  = A(val: "hello") // y : A<String>
var z = B()
print(z.insert(x)) // insert being generic accepts any A<T>
print(z.insert(y))
print(z.insert(x)) // should return (false, x) as element already added
print("\(z)")
for member in z.setOfA
{
    print("member = \(member) : \(type(of:member))")
    if let intMember = member as? A<Int>
    {
        print("   intMember = \(intMember) : \(type(of:intMember))")
    }
    else if let stringMember = member as? A<String>
    {
        print("   stringMember = \(stringMember) : \(type(of:stringMember))")
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
(true, __lldb_expr_501.A<Swift.Int>(val: 4))
(true, __lldb_expr_501.A<Swift.String>(val: "hello"))
(false, __lldb_expr_501.A<Swift.Int>(val: 4))
B(_setOfA: Set([AnyHashable(__lldb_expr_501.A<Swift.String>(val: "hello")), AnyHashable(__lldb_expr_501.A<Swift.Int>(val: 4))]))
member = A<String>(val: "hello") : AnyHashable
   stringMember = A<String>(val: "hello") : A<String>
member = A<Int>(val: 4) : AnyHashable
   intMember = A<Int>(val: 4) : A<Int>
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

If you plan on letting your struct contain `val` of a specific type, use `<T: DesiredProtocol>`. If the type doesn't matter, and your `val` can be of any type, just implement the structure as `struct A<T> {}`. `A<T>` is equal to `A<T: Any>`.

Note that your example won't compile if you intend to have `setOfA` contain `A` with different types.

> The elements in a `Set` must be hashable.
>
> In `B<T>`, `T` represents only one type. Therefore, you cannot store different types in `Set<A<T>>`.

Because of this requirement, `struct A<T>` must conform to the `Hashable` protocol, and the implementation of `B` must be changed.

```
struct A<T>: Hashable {
    var val: T

    // Implementation of Hashable
}

/// This struct should not be generic. It would constrain its setOfA to only contain the same type. 
/// By removing the generics, and use Any instead, you let each element have its own type.
struct B {
    var setOfA: Set<A<Any>>
}

var set: Set<A<Any>> = Set()
set.insert(A(val: 0 as Int))
set.insert(A(val: 1 as Float))

let b = B(setOfA: set)
```

#### Edit:

Due to the fact that you're looking for a way to insert a generic `A<T>` into `A<Any>` without specifying its type as `A<Any>` on creation, I've come up with two different ways:

```
let v1 = A(val: 5)
var v2 = A(val: 3)

aSet.insert(A(val: v2.val))
aSet.insert(withUnsafePointer(to: &v3, { return UnsafeRawPointer($0) }).assumingMemoryBound(to: A<Any>.self).pointee)
```

### Edit

If it is as you write, that `B`'s `setOfA` would only have `A<>` of a single type, it's the choice of the context whether you should use generics or not. The question is rather if `struct B` needs to be generic. `struct A` can be a value type for many different tasks, while `struct B` doesn't need to. If `B` is more specific, you could rather just write:

```
struct B {
    var setOfA: Set<A<Int>>
}
```

As above-mentioned, if you intend to have the same set contain `A<Int>` and `A<Float>`, then `var setOfA: Set<A<Any>>` is the correct way.

If `struct A` has a very specific use-case, and you don't actually need it to be generic, you should change the type of `val`. Your code should be understandable and comprehensive. I would recommend one of these solutions:

```
struct A: Hashable {
    
    var val: Any
    // or
    var val: Numeric

    // Implementation of Hashable
}
```

Comment: The problem here is that the type isn't inferred anymore. 

var aSet = Set<A<Any>>()

let v1 = A(val: 4) as A<Any>
let v2 = A(val: 5.5) as A<Any>
        
aSet.insert(v1)
aSet.insert(v2)

If I don't write - "as A<Any>" it gives me a compile-time error - "Cannot convert value of type A<Int> to expected argument type A<Any>"

Comment: @KunalShah It yields no error to me. I use Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10 Beta, but that shouldn't make a difference. I got a compile time error as well, when I tried to initialize the `Set` using an `ArrayLiteral`: `let set: Set<A<Any>> = [A(val: 0 as Int), A(val: 1 as Float)]`. The code from your comment gives me no error in Xcode.

Comment: @KunalShah Yeah, sorry. I see the problem now. The compiler wants you to explicitly write the type of the inserted struct. You have to do that on creation of `A`. You can circumvent the issue by creating a new `A` on insertion: `let v2 = A(val: 5);
    aSet.insert(A(val: v2.val))`, but that should come with overhead.

Comment: @KunalShah Any doesn't conform to Hashable therefore  you can't have a set of type Any

Comment: @LeoDabus - you can have a set of `AnyHashable` though. However that doesn't solve the OP's problem, but it might be part of a solution.

Comment: @CRD @LeoDabus He can wrap his `Any` variables in a `class` or `struct`, but if they’re only wrapping an `Any` variable, it should be considered if it’s really a good solution. It might just be better to use a `protocol`, for instance `Numeric`.

Comment: @Andreas - yes `AnyHashable` doesn't solve the problem, but I think you'll find `Numeric` doesn't either (have you tried it?) even if all the type parameters are numeric and that's not given. To have a set of `A<T>` for multiple `T` and *only* `A`'s in the set is what might prove a challenge in Swift (given that no one has offered a solution yet, unsafe constructs aside).

Comment: @CRD I just tried having `struct A<Numeric & Hashable>: Hashable`, but it wasn't so easy getting that `setOfA` to work with it - I didn't manage to get it to - at least not in this timeframe.