# Why can I return a bool with return type AnyObject? with UIKit and not with Darwin

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, darwin

I was typing some Swift code, because I was bored and haven't programmed Swift in a while.

Why does this code work when I include UIKit

```
import UIKit

public class foo {
  private var boolTest : Bool?

  init() {
    boolTest = true
  }

  public func call() -> AnyObject? {
    if let bool = boolTest {
      return bool
    }
    else {
      return nil
    }
  }
}

foo().call()
```

And when I import Darwin instead of UIKit it doesn't work.

```
import Darwin

public class foo {
  private var boolTest : Bool?

  init() {
    boolTest = true
  }

  public func call() -> AnyObject? {
    if let bool = boolTest {
      return bool
    }
    else {
      return nil
    }
  }
}

foo().call()
```

Its the exact same code except I changed UIKit to Darwin.
The error says can't return type bool to AnyObject?

It doesn't give the error message when I include UIKit.

So does anyone know what causes this?

Comment: Sounds like you should just use UIKit ; )

Comment: @kpie m really curious why it throws that error message with Darwin and not with UIKit. Hopefully someone knows why.

Comment: What happens if you import both?

Comment: @kpie that works fine as well.

Comment: And what happens if you change "AnyObject" to "Any" in the second snippet?

Comment: @kpie Then it also works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Foundation` adds automatic bridging from `Bool` to `NSNumber` (which is an `AnyObject`).

```
extension Bool : _ObjectiveCBridgeable {
    public init(_ number: NSNumber)
}
```

Comment: So NSNumber is a type while Bool is a reference... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25809168/anyobject-and-any-in-swift

Comment: Thanks for your answer, didn't know this!

Answer (score 4):

`UIKit` imports `Foundation` and `Darwin`, while `Darwin` only imports its submodules (like `MacTypes`).

The `Bool` Objective-C bridge is only declared in `Foundation`

```
extension Bool : _ObjectiveCBridgeable {
    public init(_ number: NSNumber)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import Foundation

let a: AnyObject = true
print(a, a.dynamicType) // 1 __NSCFBoolean
let b: Bool = true
print(b, b.dynamicType) // true Bool
```

there is 'free bridging' between some native swift and Objective C. Personally I hate this 'automatic' bridging, on the opposite side, if you need to mix swift with Objective C, it helps you to write 'cleaner' code. there is a lot of code around available, where this 'free bridging' is a source of unwanted functionality. i recommend you to use native swift types as much as you can. i really don't understand the idea why somebody needs to assign boolean value to variable of type AnyObject ....

check this 'smart' constructions

```
a as! NSObject == 1     // true
//a == true             // error !!!!!!
a as! NSObject == true  // true
//a == b as AnyObject   // error !!
//a as Bool == b        // error
a as! Bool == b         // true
a as! UInt == 1         // true
a as! Double == 1       // true
```