# geting error with Dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, nsdictionary

```
     let parameter : Dictionary<String,AnyObject> =  ["action":"add-playlist-item","playlist_id":self.dictPlayList.objectForKey("ID")!,"kod_id":arrayOfID]
```

error
["action": add-playlist-item, "playlist_id": 166, "kod_id": <_TtCs21_SwiftDeferredNSArray 0x7c615620>(
21,
18
)
]

_TtCs21_SwiftDeferredNSArray 0x7c615620 what does this error mean??

Comment: what is arrayOfID. give some more code

Comment: So can have some idea

Comment: var arrayOfID = [String]() ; arrayOfID = ["22","33"]

Comment: It seems like there is some issue in passing string array to anyObject

Comment: not only string i did with int too...same error..is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: I was having a similar issue. I noticed it was with the way I had made the parameter type: `Dictionary<String,AnyObject>`. When I let swift infer the type, `SwiftDeferredNSArray` went away...

Answer (score 0):

Array is a value type and it's not an object, but a struct. So it doesn't conform to AnyObject protocol. Use Any instead of AnyObject. See more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25809478/1099716) and [here](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-ID342&ved=0ahUKEwjR-raAmaXMAhXGA5oKHZOrAkEQygQIGzAA&usg=AFQjCNEI9TIAirwb6j6n6QRX726lgJ0rSw&sig2=KW6i5hfvRzr3BXr3JFv42g).

Comment: i have tried that already but alamofire doesnot support that.is there any other way to solve this??

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are using JSON parameter encoding, not URL encoding.

You may be having the same problem I was having. I was seeing `<_TtCs21_SwiftDeferredNSArray 0x7c615620>` appear in my requests too.  When I changed to JSON encoding, everything worked.  I don't think a dictionary structure like that can be properly URL encoded.  I'm not sure how you're actually making the request or I would post code.

Comment: Could you please share your code for request .I am also facing the same issue