# What is the difference between [String: AnyObject] and [String: Any]?

Tags: swift, dictionary, any, anyobject

I usually use `[String: AnyObject]`. But I noticed that Alamofire uses `[String: Any]`. I read somewhere that `Any` is "superior" than `AnyObject` or "encompasses" `AnyObject`. But other than that, I don't know if there's any different between them. Is there any downside in the long run if I define dictionary as `[String: Any]` instead of `[String: AnyObject]`? Thanks.

Comment: I believe that Any can refer to any type, including, for example, a closure/function. AnyObject needs to be an instance of a class.

Comment: @francisaugusto but I mean, why there's `AnyObject` if it can be handled by `Any`? I think there must be something that `AnyObject` can do, that `Any` can't.

Comment: please check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25809377/2450755

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini ooh okay, the last SO link really answers my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Any** allowed use to work with a mix of different types including 
function and non-class types 
such as Int, String, and Bool. According to the documentation,
the elements in this array are Structs that are value types, so in theory

**AnyObject** shouldn’t work in these cases.

we would use AnyObject for Class types because they are a little more specific than Any. But again, the use of AnyObject is just an option.

more explaination you can find here.
I hope all your doubts will clear after go through this link

https://medium.com/@mimicatcodes/any-vs-anyobject-in-swift-3-b1a8d3a02e00

Comment: I see. So I think it will be better to use [String: Any] in this case, because it's more compatible with more types. I usually store String, Int, Double, Bool, and such in my dictionary, so the use of AnyObject is actually incorrect. Thanks!

Comment: Use Any confidently in Swift