# Having trouble with a nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, firebase

I am trying to retrieve the postImageUrl from firebase but for some reason I'm getting a error from a unwrapping nil with the postImageUrl. How can I make this code work so I can retrieve the image url from firebase without causing a crash?

[Code Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZfjW.png)

[Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDM7d.jpg)

Comment: My guess is `postURL` is actually `nil`. Instead of force unwrapping things you should be using `guard let ... else` to verify that the value is valid, it's kind of the point of using optionals

Comment: Share a snippet of the post in the Firebase database so we can see what data you are trying to load into the postImageUrl

Comment: Perhaps you only need to do `let postImageUrl = dict["postImageUrl"] as! String` on line 97.

Comment: i tried that but it crash. i get the same error

Comment: Please post your code inline instead of as a screenshot.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don’t include images or links in your questions. Include code and structures as text. Links break and if they do, it invalidates the question. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Images and links are not searchable so they may not be of use to future readers.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

change this line of code 93:

```
let author = dict!["author"] as? [String: AnyObject]
```

Comment: @GerardoLeon The issue here is the that this is unwrapping an optional in an unsafe manner - if dict is nil, the app  will crash. So safely unwrapping it is best practice and/or providing default values in those cases is a good idea. Also current swift code would be `[String: Any]`. There are also alternatives for performing this function - see my answer.

Comment: @Jay firebase dictionary instance in always [String: AnyObject]. you need to check firebase documentation.

Comment: Lol. Use AnyObject when you need the flexibility of an untyped object or when you use bridged Objective-C methods and properties that return an untyped result. While it appears in the somewhat outdated documentation, a quick test in Playground should be very revealing. Try this `let x: [String: AnyObject] = ["key": "value"]` and then try this `let y: [String: Any] = ["key": "value"]` and check out the results. Also check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25809168/anyobject-and-any-in-swift) for some other reading. AnyObject is not wrong, just 'old'.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should avoid the `!` force-unwrap operator unless you can 100% prove that the value will never be `nil`, which should be a tiny minority of the time (usually when loading files included inside your application's bundle). This clearly isn't the case here, since the value *is* nil, so you should either use `if let` or `guard let` to unwrap the value, handling the case where it is `nil`, or you can use the `??` operator to provide a default value like so:

```
doSomethingWith(foo ?? "this string gets passed if foo is nil")
```

Depending on what your `Post` object is supposed to do, it's also possible that it might actually be appropriate for it to contain a `nil` value for `imageURL`. In this case, you may just want to declare its `imageURL` property as an optional by adding an `?` to the end of its type:

```
struct Post: Codable {
    ...
    let imageURL: URL? // or String? if that's what it is
    ...
}
```

In this case, you would unwrap the `imageURL` property later, when it comes time to use it.

Answer (score 0):

It's best practice to handle optionals by safely unwrapping them and providing default values in case of nil or not executing code that could crash the app.

Additionally, Firebase snapshots are quite powerful and enable you to easily drill down into child nodes.

Here's some updated code that shows those two techniques.

```
func gerAllFeedPosts() {
    REF_FEED.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let allPosts = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
        for postSnap in allPosts { //if there are no posts, no closure code will run
            let authorSnap = postSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "author")
            let uid = authorSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "uid").value as? String ?? "NO UID!"
            let username = authorSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "username").value as? String ?? "NO USERNAME!"
```