# Referencing instance method 'findIdxOf' on 'Array' requires that 'FeedData' be a class type

Tags: swift

I try to use generic method in order to find the index of the item in the array

```
public extension Array where Element: AnyObject {
    func findIdxOf<T: AnyObject>(_ item: T) -> Int? {
        return self.firstIndex{ $0 === item }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
struct FeedData: Codable {
...
}

var currentFeedsArr: [FeedData] = []
var feed = FeedData()

let idx: Int? = currentFeedsArr.findIdxOf(feed)
```

Error that I get -

```
Instance method 'findIdxOf' requires that 'FeedData' be a class type
Referencing instance method 'findIdxOf' on 'Array' requires that 'FeedData' be a class type
```

How to solve it?

Comment: You need to understand what means `AnyObject`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25809168/anyobject-and-any-in-swift it's not for struct. That's why. Later, you might need to use `Equatable` to decides what means the use  of `==` between to struct instances...

Comment: It's because of [AnyObject](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/anyobject).

Comment: What you need is `extension Collection where Element: Equatable` and no need to make your method generic. Just make `item: Element`. Besides that not sure why would you recreate a method that is already present `firstIndex(of:)` no need to use a predicate `firstIndex(where:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple. You said

```
where Element: AnyObject
```

That means: "Element must be a class." That is *exactly* what AnyObject means. (And your use of `===` implies that you know this, since only a class can be used with `===`, the identity operator.)

So your `findIdxOf` applies only to an array whose element is a class. But FeedData is not a class. It is a struct.

So when you try to apply `findIdxOf` to an array of FeedData, the compiler complains.

---

Apart from that, it is unclear what your purpose was in creating this generic. If the goal was to use `firstIndex(of:)` with FeedData, then throw away your `findIdxOf` and simply declare FeedData as Equatable. If the goal was truly to implement a special version of `firstIndex(of:)` that compares class instances for identity, then declare FeedData as a class.